# Ag-grid how can I Stop / End Editing on Navigation Key Down?

Tags: ag-grid, nuxt.js

As ag-grid docs goes like:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#stop-end-editing

Navigation Key Down: Editing will stop, accepting changes, and editing will move to the next cell in the direction of the navigation key.

So, when I press on one of the navigation keys, I spect the grid to stop editing, accept the change and move to the next cell y the direcction I pressed. But that is not happening.

I tried solve this listening to events, so I did with cellKeyDown event:

```
      <ag-grid-vue
      style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      :columnDefs="columnDefs"
      :rowData="rowData"
      @gridReady="onGridReady"
      @cellKeyDown="debug"
      @cellEditingStopped="$emit('registro_modificado', $event)"
      :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
      :navigateToNextCell="navigateToNextCell"></ag-grid-vue>
```

So listen to the cellKeyDown event is handeled by 'debug' method

```
  debug(event){
    console.log(event)
    if (event.event.key == 'ArrowUp' || event.event.key == 'ArrowDown'|| event.event.key == 'ArrowLeft' || event.event.key == 'ArrowRight'){
      // @ts-ignore
      this.gridOptions.stopEditing()
      // this.navigateToNextCell(this.parametrosKeyNav)
      // @ts-ignore
      // this.gridOptions.navigateToNextCell()
      // this.gridOptions.tabToNextCell()
      // this.gridOptions.startEditingCell()
    }
  }
```

So far, this.gridOptions.stopEditing() stopped editing succesfully. But navigating to the next cell in the direction the nav key was pressed, is something that I can't figure out by now. All the method and directive commented below the stopEditing() line had failed to acomplish navigation in the direction the nav key was pressed

Comment: That documentation doesn't say (or no longer says) that editing will stop when a navigation key (e.g. arrows up or down) is pressed. I am having the same problem though that I cannot capture these keypresses when the cell is being edited in `onCellKeyPress`.